# kubectl error: cannot add key dashboard.yaml, another key by that name already exists

Tags: kubernetes

Our system architect left and I'm thrown into a deep water managing Kubernetes cluster.
I'm trying to update ssl-secret on our kubernetes cluster, using the following command

```
kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secret \
        --from-file=./$CERT_FILE \
        --from-file=./$KEY_FILE \
        --dry-run=client \
        -o yaml |
         kubectl apply -f -
```

When I run it, however, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot add key dashboard.yaml, another key by that name already exists
error: no objects passed to apply
```

I'm not sure how to resolve it. Tried Google and Stack Overflow searches, but none of the questions are actually related to this error.

Comment: @P....  I tried to run the following before the command above: ` kubectl -n zone-system delete secret ssl-secret ` also, there are only one .pem and one .key files

Comment: `grep -rE` for `deployment.yaml[ ]*:` in your work directory.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not passing a duplicate key names `dashboard.yaml`. you are using two files as input for secrets. `CERT_FILE` and `KEY_FILE`, make sure that there is no duplicate key in these two files, specially `dashboard.yaml`.

To demo the issue, passing a key called `dashboard.yaml` twice and getting the same error while creating secret. Note that, `from-literal` is used here for sake of simplicity.

You should `grep` for `"dashboard.yaml"` on `CERT_FILE` and `KEY_FILE`.

```
    kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-literal=dashboard.yaml=supersecret --from-literal=dashboard.yaml=supersecret1
    error: cannot add key dashboard.yaml, another key by that name already exists
```

The second error `error: no objects passed to apply` is because, there is no `yaml` is generated from `dry-run`.

**Further debugging result:**

The `echo` of your command is returning both the variables `CERT_FILE` and `KEY_FILE` as empty and they are both pointing to `./` leading to duplication.

```
root@ip-10-10-10-118:/home/code/kubernetes/dev1# echo "kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secret --from-file=./$CERT_FILE --from-file=./$KEY_FILE --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -" 
kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secret --from-file=./ --from-file=./ --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: I run the command as is, not passing any key names. and, yes, i get the second error. not sure about the first one

Comment: you are passing two files, you are using `--from-file` option. This means, secrets are fetched form those two files. Eg: `CERT_FILE` and `KEY_FILE`. so its coming from there. `grep` for `deployment.yaml` in those two files please.

Comment: My setup.sh contains `CERT_FILE="wild.zonetv.cloud.cert.pem"
KEY_FILE="wild.zonetv.cloud.key"` these files are the actual pem file with the server certificate and the chain, and the certificate key. there's no deployment.yaml in any of them

Comment: can you do `grep -r dashboard.yaml $PWD`  ?

Comment: Sure. `root@ip-10-10-10-118:/home/code/kubernetes/dev1# grep -r dashboard.yaml $PWD
/home/code/kubernetes/dev1/setup.sh:    kubectl apply -f dashboard.yaml`      I do have dashboard.yaml in the working directory. It has all the kubernetes dashboard settings, and I want to replace the existing secret named ssl-secret

Comment: When I do `root@ip-10-10-10-118:/home/code/kubernetes/dev1# grep -r dashboard.yaml $CERT_FILE` I get 
`setup.sh:    kubectl apply -f dashboard.yaml`

Comment: it is weird, sorry I do not have much to guess error is pointing to duplication.  to debug, can you put your original `kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secre .........` command in the question inside `echo` and print it, to see the o/p of `echo`. Need to check if `--from-file` is getting right file as input. its trivial but worth a check.

Comment: Sure. I appreciate your help. Here it is: `root@ip-10-10-10-118:/home/code/kubernetes/dev1# echo "kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secret --from-file=./$CERT_FILE --from-file=./$KEY_FILE --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -"` and the output is 
`kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secret --from-file=./ --from-file=./ --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: `$CERT_FILE` and `$KEY_FILE` are empty in the echo o/p and both are pointing to `./` same location, which contain same file(`dashboard.yaml`).

Comment: You need to check why `--from-file=./ --from-file=./` they both are empty ? check the variable assignment of the two vairables. I am certain the issue will be fixed once you fix the two variables.

Comment: Oh my. So should I replace the $CERT_FILE and $KEY_FILE with the actual file names?

Comment: yes, first try with the actual file names, if that help, you can debug why those vairables are empty and address that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This worked: `kubectl -n zone-system create secret generic ssl-secret --from-file=./wild.zonetv.cloud.cert.pem --from-file=./wild.zonetv.cloud.key --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -` result: 
`secret/ssl-secret created`

Comment: Just did, thank you for your help! Now need to figure out how to update the kubernetes with the updated dashboard